# Php links and htaccess messing something up

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

So here's my problem, everything is working except for one thing.
Here is the html code:
'

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="info">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="galerija">Galerija</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

So when i click on info or kontakt it redirects me perfictly but when i click on the galerija link i takes me to the root of that lik:
www**/galerija/
insted of www**/galerija

i used htaccess to change the URL's to be user friendly. Here's the htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Any ideas ?

If it helps here's the website: http://www.britannica.rs

Comment: Is that the actual source code? Are you sure there are no typos? Because with the RewriteRule in your htaccess like this it can't do what you say.

Comment: yeah that's the full code. :/
it's working on other link's just the galery(galerija) link is not working as it should... :/

Comment: The `<a>` elements should be inside the `<li>` elements. Not related to the error you describe, but worth mentioning.

Comment: I know that but this way i can make larger area clickable and make a better hover effect.. :) thx for the mention. ;)

Comment: @Vladimir you can achieve that with CSS when you put the `a` inside the `li`. You can get problems with it if your HTML is invalid.

Comment: Yep I agree totally with @putvande. Just put the *a* inside the *li* tag and give it *display: block; width:100%; height: 100%;*.

Comment: You can add "/?" to remove the trailing slash. RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]

Comment: I'v changed the <a> and <ul> tags but still nothing, it still redirects me to the root...

Btw thx for the tip! :)

And tried your way @NoWiS but still nothing.

Comment: Mhh, didn't saw you had linked the website. It seems that a folder named "galerija" exists. Thus the second RewriteCond stops before the rewrite rule.

Comment: Yeah that was the solution! :)))

Can you just post it as the answer so i can accept it! :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a folder named "galerija" at the root of the website.
Thus, the second RewriteCond is triggered, and the RewriteRule is not applied.

Comment: Than you very much! again! :)

Answer (score 0):

This might not solve the entire problem but when using html bullet lists use it this way:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="info">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="galerija">Galerija</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

For the redirect using file with no extensions try

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php
```